# Where is the program scheduler on the iPad version?

Tags: ios, prison-architect, mobile

I am trying to schedule an alcoholics counseling program to a specific common room on the iOS (ipad) version of Prison Architect.

I have micromanagement unlocked, and I have the program created, but I can't figure out how to assign it to a specific room (I have two common rooms). All the stuff I found on the internet describes a program scheduler on the programs tab somewhere, but I can't find anything like that on the iPad and I'm wondering if the Steam version is different.

It's also a problem for my drug rehab program. I have two infirmaries; one with 4 beds, and one with 10 that I made specifically for the program. But it's using the smaller infirmary and really bottlenecking things. I can't figure out how to get it to use the larger one.

How do I assign rooms to programs?

Comment: In the Programs tab there should be a button "Edit schedule" at the bottom.

Comment: @Xander I don't see it: https://imgur.com/NEYOAjY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the program scheduler isn't available on iOS or consoles.

Unfortunately I don't have any sources to back this up other than the testimonies of friends who played on console/PC and iPad/PC and weren't able to locate the scheduler button.